# Need to wrap functions in a standard try/catch function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, anonymous-function

I know there are lots of delegate/func examples but I can't find any examples that will work for me, or I just don't understand them.

I'm using asp.net MVC for a website, and the website needs some web service calls for an outside application to interact with my app.  These all need a function to execute (going to db and whatnot), and return a similar data model every time.  I want to wrap each call in a try/catch and populate the model.

Here is the generic code that happens every call.

```
var model = new ResponseDataModel();
try
{
     //execute different code here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    model.Error = true;
    model.Message = ex.ToString();
}
return View(model); // will return JSON or XML depending on what the caller specifies
```

This is one of the controller methods/ functions that I am using

```
public ActionResult MillRequestCoil()
{
    var model = new ResponseDataModel();
    try
    {
        /* edit */
        //specific code
        string coilId = "CC12345";

        //additional code
        model.Data = dataRepository.doSomethingToCoil(coilId);

        //replaced code
        //model.Data = new { Coil = coilId, M3 = "m3 message", M5 = "m5 message" };
        model.Message = string.Format("Coil {0} sent successfully", coilId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         model.Error = true;
         model.Message = ex.ToString();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I would like to be able to somehow convert the specific function to a variable to pass into the generic code.  I've looked at delegates and anonymous funcs but it's pretty confusing until you do it yourself.

Comment: Can you pass an object of type `Action` to the methods? This would allow you to pass your real method to `MillRequestCoil` etc. Not sure whether this would work in ASP.NET though.

Comment: @ChrisF, could you show an example?? I think that's what I want to do, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: The existing answers show what I was suggesting. I'm not familiar enough with ASP.NET to know whether the code I could suggest would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following somewhere accessible:

```
public static ActionResult SafeViewFromModel(
    Action<ResponseDataModel> setUpModel)
{
    var model = new ResponseDataModel();
    try
    {
        setUpModel(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        model.Error = true;
        model.Message = ex.ToString();
    }
    return View(model); 
}
```

and then call it like:

```
public ActionResult MillRequestCoil()
{
    return MyHelperClass.SafeViewFromModel(model =>
    {
        string coilId = "CC12345";
        model.Data = new {
            Coil = coilId,
            M3 = "m3 message",
            M5 = "m5 message" };
        model.Message = string.Format("Coil {0} sent successfully", coilId);
    });
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to the code.  I wont' just be creating an object, I'll be executing functions and what not.

Comment: You should still be able to do this! E.g. if you could see `dataRepository` in the body of `MillRequestCoil`, you will still be able to see it inside the lambda function (`model => { ... }` bit).

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IAction{
    public void doAction(ResponseDataModel model);
}

public class Action1 : IAction
{
    public void doAction(ResponseDataModel model)
    {
        string coilId = "CC12345";
        model.Data = new { Coil = coilId, M3 = "m3 message", M5 = "m5 message" };
        model.Message = string.Format("Coil {0} sent successfully", coilId);
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public ActionResult MillRequestCoil(IAction action)
    {
        var model = new ResponseDataModel();
        try
        {
            //specific code
            action.doAction(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.Error = true;
            model.Message = ex.ToString();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var result = MillRequestCoil(new Action1());
```

or execute other code

```
var result = MillRequestCoil(new ActionXY());
```

Comment: This seems rather complicated just to reimplement `Action<>`.

Comment: Super answer. VERY minor nitpick; would respectfully suggest name of interface be prefaced with "I" to indicate interface nomenclature, so the declaration of MillRequestCoil (et al) would be an object implementing the interface rather than a subclass of a higher-level object...

Comment: There is an initial level of complication, but the OP's problem indicates a need to reuse for multiple situations, so the robustness seems like a winner to me. Just my $0.02 :)

Comment: The problem with this is I'd have to create a class per function that I want to use.  I have about 20 of these functions, and wanted to keep the code to a min.  it does work though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of Rawling's answer, that I believe has better readability:

```
public ActionResult MillRequestCoil()
{
    var model = CreateResponseDataModel(RunSpecificCode);

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult MillDoSomethingElse ()
{
    var model = CreateResponseDataModel(RunOtherCode);

    return View(model);
}

private ResponseDataModel CreateResponseDataModel(Action<ResponseDataModel> action)
{
    var model = new ResponseDataModel();
    try
    {
        action(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        model.Error = true;
        model.Message = ex.ToString();
    }
    return model;
}

private void RunSpecificCode(ResponseDataModel model)
{
    /* edit */
    //specific code
    const string coilId = "CC12345";

    //additional code
    model.Data = _dataRepository.DoSomethingToCoil(coilId);

    //replaced code
    //model.Data = new { Coil = coilId, M3 = "m3 message", M5 = "m5 message" };
    model.Message = string.Format("Coil {0} sent successfully", coilId);
}

private void RunOtherCode(ResponseDataModel obj)
{
    // some other piece of code
}
```

No lambdas, and nice separation of concerns between your specific code and the template code for the try/catch and model building stuff.